# Create Xml data into Jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, properties, load

im trying to create an xml data into JSP using a resource file:

MyData.properties :

```
nombreOfQuestions=2
question1.description=what is the color?
question1.responseValue1=Red
question1.responseValue2=yellow
question1.responseValue3=white
question2.description=what is the Weight?
question2.responseValue1=70
question2.responseValue2=75
question2.responseValue3=80
```

myJsp.jsp :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page import="MessageResourcesHelper"%>
<%
 MessageResourcesHelper helper = new MessageResourcesHelper (pageContext, "MyData");
 String nombreOfQuestions= helper.getProperty ("nombreOfQuestions",0);
 %>

<Question>
 <description>what is the color?</description>
 <response>
     <value>Red</value>
     <value>Yellow</value>
     <value>White</value>
 </response>
</Question>

<Question>
  <description>what is the Weight?</description>
  <response>
    <value>70</value>
    <value>75</value>
    <value>80</value>
  </response>
 </Question>
```

is there any way to use java to recuperate the "description" and the "values" dynamically from myData.properties whatever the nombre of question i have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the properties file, iterate over the keys.

For each key, you'll have a question number, and a property of that question. For each question's response properties you'll have a response number, and the response value.

Create either a map, or a collection, of `Question` objects. Each `Question` object has a `description` property, and a collection of response strings.

The `description` property of each `Question` is set when you iterate over that question's `description` property. For each response value property, add the property value to the collection of responses.

To get it back to XML, you can either expose the question list to the JSP and iterate over each question (and inside that loop, iterate over the question's responses). Or you could marshall the object directly to XML via any of the normal Java libraries for doing so.

You don't really need the number of questions property since they're enumerated in the property names themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. but the probleme is that i dont know how to iterate propreties file after load

Comment: @naj_ib Oh. Hm. Have you considered looking at the [API docs for it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)? There's a [method in there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames()) that seems like it might help.

Comment: it's done and now my jsp is ready to be loaded by a Jaxb converter doing :      try {
                JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = null;
                synchronized (_unMarshaller) {                
                    jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<?>)    _unMarshaller.unmarshal(inStream);
                }  (with inStream is my jsp as InputStream) but i get this Jaxbexception :      (JaxbHelper.java:115) unexpected element (uri:"", local:"script").     Expected elements are <{}Questionnaire>

Comment: i found the probleme, its because of the authentification page ! when jaxb calls the jsp, the authentification page is loaded before to access to the questionnaire jsp. i did this test, i called "http://localhost/jsp/questionnaire.jsp" actually, authentification page is loaded, i insert login/pwd, then the jsp was loaded and i got the xml ! is that any way to fix this issue?? thanks a lot for your help Dave